# Writing to Docx using python-docx eliminates styling?

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I am writing a code for machine translation. I am getting input from a docx file. I am able to extract the contents of the file, but after translation, when I write back to the same docx file, it either writes in plain text format or just eliminates the font and paragraph styles.

Is there a method to write back to a docx file with same font as what's already in the file? Like keeping track of XMl structure of file.

i have more than hundred paragraphs and it is a lengthy task to apply styling to each paragraph manually through code, so is there a module which first provides xml structure like this.

```
    <w:body>
    <w:p>
    <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
    </w:pPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r><w:t>Introduction</w:t></w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
    <w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">Please fill your name in the space 
     provided</w:t></w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
    <w:pPr>
```

and on writing back it should add to that current position position between

```
    <w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve"> Please fill your name in the space 
    provided  </w:t></w:r>
```

for examle:

```
    <w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve"> Bitte füllen Sie bitte Ihren Namen aus  
    </w:t></w:r>
```

so that style is preserved and old sentence is replaced by new one.

Comment: Keeping track of the XML structure is literally exactly what python-docx does. You are screwing something up and not showing it to us.

Comment: Add to your question the minimum Python code that produces the result you describe. If it's over 20 lines it's not the minimum code :)

Comment: Check out this page in the documentation to understand more about character formatting, and how it must be specified at the *Run* level. You'll need to read font details from the source and apply them to the target runs to achieve what you're asking for. http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html#apply-character-formatting

Answer (score 0):

It's a painstaking work. You need to iterate over text of runs in paragraphs, rather than by mere paragraph's texts.

```
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    for run in paragraph.runs:
         #print run.text
         #print run._element.xml
         run.text = 'translated text'
```

Note, the paragraphs are split in runs based on styling and other odds.
So, eg.:

a *new* comfortable **chair**

will be consisted of minimum 4 runs...